# Installed wrong libc6-dev Version

Tags: 14.04, apt, package-management, dpkg, dependencies

I wanted to install an ARK server on my ubuntu server 14.04 LTS and I think I completely messed up my system entirely.

What I did was [this](http://ark.gamepedia.com/Dedicated_Server_Setup).

```
nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

and added this to the file

```
# Experimental/unstable (sid) repositories
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian experimental main
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian sid main
```

and then:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install libc6-dev
```

But now I have broken dependencies. 
I tried all the standard stuff.

```
apt-get install -f
apt-get upgrade -f
apt-get dist-upgrade
```

And tried a lot of things I read in the web but
nothing works.

The system is running smoothly and everything works 
except upgrading it or installing new packages because
the unmet dependencies block it.

The output of `apt-get upgrade` is:

```
libc-bin : depends on: libc6 (< 2.20) but 2.22-3 is installed
libc-l10n : brocken: locales (< 2.21-0experimental1) but 2.13+git20120306-12.1 is installed
libc6 : brocken: locales (< 2.22) but 2.13+git20120306-12.1 is installed
```

I translated the output from german in english.
So what I read out of it is that `libc6` is to new? So I have to replace it with an older version?

I have no clue. I hope there is a solution other then wiping the disc.
I saw the error to late so I cannot roll back in time far enough to fix it.
What I did was not smart at all... But year... learned some lessons... :-/

Thanks for your time and effort reading this and thanks for your help. :-)

Edit

This is the Output of `apt-cache policy libc6 libc6-dev locales`

```
libc6:
  Installiert:           2.22-2
  Installationskandidat: 2.22-2
  Versionstabelle:
 *** 2.22-2 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.19-0ubuntu6.7 0
        500 ftp://ftp.stratoserver.net/pub/linux/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 ftp://ftp.stratoserver.net/pub/linux/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
     2.19-0ubuntu6 0
        500 ftp://ftp.stratoserver.net/pub/linux/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
libc6-dev:
  Installiert:           2.22-2
  Installationskandidat: 2.22-2
  Versionstabelle:
 *** 2.22-2 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.19-0ubuntu6.7 0
        500 ftp://ftp.stratoserver.net/pub/linux/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 ftp://ftp.stratoserver.net/pub/linux/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
     2.19-0ubuntu6 0
        500 ftp://ftp.stratoserver.net/pub/linux/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
locales:
  Installiert:           2.13+git20120306-12.1
  Installationskandidat: 2.13+git20120306-12.1
  Versionstabelle:
 *** 2.13+git20120306-12.1 0
        500 ftp://ftp.stratoserver.net/pub/linux/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.13+git20120306-12 0
        500 ftp://ftp.stratoserver.net/pub/linux/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

Edit

The output of `apt-get install libc6=2.19-0ubuntu6.7 libc6-dev=2.19-0ubuntu6.7`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc-dev-bin : Depends: libc6 (> 2.22) but 2.19-0ubuntu6.7 is to be installed
                Recommends: manpages-dev but it is not going to be installed
 libc-l10n : Breaks: locales (< 2.21-0experimental1) but 2.13+git20120306-12.1 is to be installed
 libc6-dev : Depends: libc-dev-bin (= 2.19-0ubuntu6.7)
 libc6-i386 : Depends: libc6 (= 2.22-2) but 2.19-0ubuntu6.7 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Edit

The output of `apt-cache policy libc-dev-bin libc-l10n libc6-dev libc6-i386`

```
libc-dev-bin:
  Installed: 2.22-2
  Candidate: 2.22-2
  Version table:
 *** 2.22-2 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.19-0ubuntu6.7 0
        500 ftp://ftp.stratoserver.net/pub/linux/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 ftp://ftp.stratoserver.net/pub/linux/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
     2.19-0ubuntu6 0
        500 ftp://ftp.stratoserver.net/pub/linux/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
libc-l10n:
  Installed: 2.22-0experimental3
  Candidate: 2.22-0experimental3
  Version table:
 *** 2.22-0experimental3 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libc6-dev:
  Installed: 2.22-2
  Candidate: 2.22-2
  Version table:
 *** 2.22-2 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.19-0ubuntu6.7 0
        500 ftp://ftp.stratoserver.net/pub/linux/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 ftp://ftp.stratoserver.net/pub/linux/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
     2.19-0ubuntu6 0
        500 ftp://ftp.stratoserver.net/pub/linux/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
libc6-i386:
  Installed: 2.22-2
  Candidate: 2.22-2
  Version table:
 *** 2.22-2 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.19-0ubuntu6.7 0
        500 ftp://ftp.stratoserver.net/pub/linux/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 ftp://ftp.stratoserver.net/pub/linux/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
     2.19-0ubuntu6 0
        500 ftp://ftp.stratoserver.net/pub/linux/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

Edit

The output of `apt-get purge libc-l10n`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc-bin : Depends: libc6 (< 2.20) but 2.22-2 is to be installed
 libc6 : Breaks: locales (< 2.22) but 2.13+git20120306-12.1 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

The output of `apt-get install libc-dev-bin=2.19-0ubuntu6.7 libc6-dev=2.19-0ubuntu6.7 libc6-i386=2.19-0ubuntu6.7`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc-bin : Depends: libc6 (< 2.20) but 2.22-2 is to be installed
 libc-dev-bin : Depends: libc6 (< 2.20) but 2.22-2 is to be installed
                Recommends: manpages-dev but it is not going to be installed
 libc-l10n : Breaks: locales (< 2.21-0experimental1) but 2.13+git20120306-12.1 is to be installed
 libc6 : Breaks: locales (< 2.22) but 2.13+git20120306-12.1 is to be installed
 libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.19-0ubuntu6.7) but 2.22-2 is to be installed
 libc6-i386 : Depends: libc6 (= 2.19-0ubuntu6.7) but 2.22-2 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: Please add the output of `apt-cache policy libc6 libc6-dev locales ` to your question and notify me with a comment when you're done.

Comment: And the guide you linked did **not** say to update libc6 like that: *"The game server requires glibc 2.14 or greater. **Ubuntu 14.04** (and newer) and Debian 8 (Jessie) **satisfy this requirement automatically**, but older versions, such as Debian 7 (Wheezy), do not. To install the required version of glibc **on a Debian 7 (Wheezy)** host: ..."* The next time, you should read the entire guide and not just paste the commands.

Comment: @ByteCommander I Added the output of the command.

Comment: Just a hint for the future, to get English command output you can add `LANG=C` before it, like `LANG=C sudo apt-get update` or `LANG=C apt-cache policy libc6`.

Comment: Okay, please add the output of `apt-cache policy libc-dev-bin libc-l10n libc6-dev libc6-i386`.

Comment: @ByteCommander Okay. I added the output of `apt-cache policy libc-dev-bin libc-l10n libc6-dev libc6-i386` to the Question.

Comment: I edited my answer and added the next wave of commands. Please report back if they solve it or if more errors come up. And you could try to install `aptitude` (`sudo apt-get install aptitude`), we can then use it later to check for more packages that should get downgraded which we did not spot yet. Also please run `sudo apt-get clean` if you haven't done that already.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We need to downgrade the `libc6` related packages again that you accidentally upgraded from the Debian Sid repository.

We first empty your package cache to prevent accidentally reinstalling the improper packages from there although you already disabled the repository again using this command:

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

Then we downgrade all the problematic `libc`-related packages to the correct version from the official Ubuntu repositories and remove the not available `libc-l10n` one using this long command:

```
sudo apt-get install libc6=2.19-0ubuntu6.7 libc6-dev=2.19-0ubuntu6.7 libc6-i386=2.19-0ubuntu6.7 libc-dev-bin=2.19-0ubuntu6.7 libc-bin=2.19-0ubuntu6.7 libc-l10n-
```

This will work. (You already confirmed that it works)

Comment: The First command broad up some dependency problems. I added the output to the Question. So I guess more packages have to be downgraded? Thanks for your answer and time :-)

Comment: I added the output of `apt-get purge libc-l10n` and `apt-get install libc-dev-bin=2.19-0ubuntu6.7 libc6-dev=2.19-0ubuntu6.7 libc6-i386=2.19-0ubuntu6.7` to the Question

Comment: Try this command that should do all the stuff our previous commands were supposed to do at once: `sudo apt-get install libc6=2.19-0ubuntu6.7 libc6-dev=2.19-0ubuntu6.7 libc6-i386=2.19-0ubuntu6.7 libc-dev-bin=2.19-0ubuntu6.7 libc-bin=2.19-0ubuntu6.7 libc-l10n-`

Comment: Thank you. It worked. All dependencies are right. Finally I can update/upgrade my packages. Learned a lot...

Comment: This came across at the end of the day! Thanks a lot, wasted whole day.

Answer (score 0):

You could solve issue by downgrade `libc6`

```
apt-get install **--reinstall** libc6=2.15-0ubuntu10.15 libc6-dev=2.15-0ubuntu10.15
apt-get check
```

If you met the similar error of Bill Z, please try following commands

```
mkdir -p /var/backup/usr/share/doc/libc6/
mv /usr/share/doc/libc6/* /var/backup/usr/share/doc/libc6/
apt-get install --reinstall libc6=2.15-0ubuntu10.15 libc6-dev=2.15-0ubuntu10.15
apt-get check
apt-get -f install
```