# Installed wrong libc6 on ubuntu 14.04 and now I'm lost

Tags: 14.04, apt, package-management, dependencies

Before anyone says use the search function, I did, and I found a topic very similar ([Installed wrong libc6-dev Version](https://askubuntu.com/questions/749076/installed-wrong-libc6-dev-version?newreg=845847ee2db74bc692d898824dff8ec9)) so I will provide the same outputs from commands that were used there, but I'm too newb on ubuntu to adapt the solution to my problem :/

Onto the topic, I was installing some stuff onto my server and one post suggested tampering with the sources.list files, so I did and I knew it was a bad idea...

Fastforward to now I cant use `apt-get install`, `apt-get upgrade` or anything in `apt` due to it telling me the `libc6` library is too new, and I don't know how to downgrade it because the dependencies are all mixed up :S Pls Help!

The following are outputs of commands I tried, which were also asked for by the OP of the other post:

Output of `apt-get upgrade` :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc-bin : Depends: libc6 (< 2.20) but 2.22-13 is installed
 libc-l10n : Breaks: locales (< 2.21-1)
 libc6 : Breaks: locales (< 2.22)
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

Output of `apt-cache policy libc6 libc6-dev locales` :

```
Installed: 2.22-13
  Candidate: 2.23-1
  Version table:
     2.23-1 0
        500 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ sid/main amd64 Packages
 *** 2.22-13 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.19-0ubuntu6.9 0
        500 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
     2.19-0ubuntu6 0
        500 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
libc6-dev:
  Installed: 2.22-13
  Candidate: 2.23-1
  Version table:
     2.23-1 0
        500 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ sid/main amd64 Packages
 *** 2.22-13 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.19-0ubuntu6.9 0
        500 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
     2.19-0ubuntu6 0
        500 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
locales:
  Installed: 2.13+git20120306-12.1
  Candidate: 2.23-1
  Version table:
     2.23-1 0
        500 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ sid/main amd64 Packages
 *** 2.13+git20120306-12.1 0
        500 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.13+git20120306-12 0
        500 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

Output of `apt-get install libc6=2.19-0ubuntu6.7 libc6-dev=2.19-0ubuntu6.7` :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Version '2.19-0ubuntu6.7' for 'libc6' was not found
E: Version '2.19-0ubuntu6.7' for 'libc6-dev' was not found
```

Output of `apt-cache policy libc-dev-bin libc-l10n libc6-dev libc6-i386` :

```
libc-dev-bin:
  Installed: 2.22-13
  Candidate: 2.23-1
  Version table:
     2.23-1 0
        500 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ sid/main amd64 Packages
 *** 2.22-13 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.19-0ubuntu6.9 0
        500 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
     2.19-0ubuntu6 0
        500 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
libc-l10n:
  Installed: 2.22-13
  Candidate: 2.23-1
  Version table:
     2.23-1 0
        500 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ sid/main amd64 Packages
 *** 2.22-13 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libc6-dev:
  Installed: 2.22-13
  Candidate: 2.23-1
  Version table:
     2.23-1 0
        500 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ sid/main amd64 Packages
 *** 2.22-13 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.19-0ubuntu6.9 0
        500 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
     2.19-0ubuntu6 0
        500 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
libc6-i386:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.23-1
  Version table:
     2.23-1 0
        500 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ sid/main amd64 Packages
     2.19-0ubuntu6.9 0
        500 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
     2.19-0ubuntu6 0
        500 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

Output of `apt-get purge libc-l10n` :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc-bin : Depends: libc6 (< 2.20) but 2.22-13 is to be installed
 libc6 : Breaks: locales (< 2.22)
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Output of `apt-get install libc-dev-bin=2.19-0ubuntu6.7 libc6-dev=2.19-0ubuntu6.7 libc6-i386=2.19-0ubuntu6.7`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Version '2.19-0ubuntu6.7' for 'libc-dev-bin' was not found
E: Version '2.19-0ubuntu6.7' for 'libc6-dev' was not found
E: Version '2.19-0ubuntu6.7' for 'libc6-i386' was not found
```

Output of the final command that apparently fixed it for the other person `sudo apt-get install libc6=2.19-0ubuntu6.7 libc6-dev=2.19-0ubuntu6.7 libc6-i386=2.19-0ubuntu6.7 libc-dev-bin=2.19-0ubuntu6.7 libc-bin=2.19-0ubuntu6.7 libc-l10n-` :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Version '2.19-0ubuntu6.7' for 'libc6' was not found
E: Version '2.19-0ubuntu6.7' for 'libc6-dev' was not found
E: Version '2.19-0ubuntu6.7' for 'libc6-i386' was not found
E: Version '2.19-0ubuntu6.7' for 'libc-dev-bin' was not found
```

I can see that it was "not found", but I have no idea how to fix this at all.

I also ran the following `sudo apt-get install libc6=2.19-0ubuntu6.9 libc6-dev=2.19-0ubuntu6.9 libc6-i386=2.19-0ubuntu6.9 libc-dev-bin=2.19-0ubuntu6.9 libc-bin=2.19-0ubuntu6.9 libc-l10n-` and it gave me :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package
```

Thank you very much for reading, hoping there is someone out there who can help.

P.S. `apt-get update` gives me this, I also have no idea what this all means :/

```
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://httpredir.debian.org sid InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 8B48AD6246925553 NO_PUBKEY 7638D0442B90D010
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package dh-systemd
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package libjpeg62
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package php-psr-http-message-implementation
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package php-psr-log-implementation
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package php-seclib
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package php-sabre-http
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package php-math-biginteger
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package pypy-cffi
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package pypy-cffi-backend-api-max
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package pypy-cffi-backend-api-min
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package python-cffi-backend-api-max
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package python-cffi-backend-api-min
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package python3-cffi-backend-api-max
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package python3-cffi-backend-api-min
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package libjpeg62
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package pypy-cffi
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package pypy-cffi-backend-api-max
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package pypy-cffi-backend-api-min
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package python-cffi-backend-api-max
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package python-cffi-backend-api-min
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package python3-cffi-backend-api-max
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package python3-cffi-backend-api-min
```

Edit: Here is my sources.list file (something probably wrong here too):

```
deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian sid main contrib non-free
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian sid main contrib non-free
## Note, this file is written by cloud-init on first boot of an instance
## modifications made here will not survive a re-bundle.
## if you wish to make changes you can:
## a.) add 'apt_preserve_sources_list: true' to /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg
##     or do the same in user-data
## b.) add sources in /etc/apt/sources.list.d
## c.) make changes to template file /etc/cloud/templates/sources.list.tmpl
#

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu trusty main restricted
deb-src http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu trusty main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu trusty-updates main restricted
deb-src http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu trusty-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu trusty universe
deb-src http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu trusty universe
deb http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu trusty-updates universe
deb-src http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu trusty-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu trusty multiverse
deb-src http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu trusty multiverse
deb http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu trusty-updates multiverse
deb-src http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu trusty-updates multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from the 'backports'
## repository.
## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Comment that `http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/` repository to disable it
2. Update package list

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
3. Force remove `libc-l10n`

   ```
   sudo dpkg remove libc-l10n
   ```
4. Check for packages names and available versions

   ```
   apt-cache policy libc6* locales
   ```
5. Downgrade the installed libc packages

   ```
   sudo apt-get install libc-bin=2.19-0ubuntu6.9 libc6-dev=2.19-0ubuntu6.9 libc6-i386=2.19-0ubuntu6.9 locales=2.19-0ubuntu6.9
   ```

   I'm not sure about which the complete list but if you get a problem, update the question with the output of `apt-cache policy libc6* locales`
6. Check if we miss anything

   ```
   sudo apt-get -f install
   ```