# Trying to install skype on ubuntu mate 1.21

Tags: apt, package-management, sound, skype, mate

I have Ubuntu Mate 1.21 loaded on my Raspberry pi, and thought I would be able to load Skype on it, for a stereo project for my truck. (thought it would be nice to have a video phone in my truck, Skype and USB camera w/ Linux driver).

I have done everything that it says from running/reading [this web page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/749076/installed-wrong-libc6-dev-version) , I am beginning to think that Skype is not meant to be ran on Ubuntu Mate for Raspberry Pi...... this is what I get after I tell it the command to run in 386 mode (for lack of a better term) and then I tell it to install skype-bins

```
skype-bin:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.7) but it is not installable
                  Depends: libgcc1:i386 (>= 1:4.1.1) but it is not installable
                  Depends: libqt4-dbus:i386 (>= 4:4.5.3) but it is not installable
                  Depends: libqt4-network:i386 (>= 4:4.8.0) but it is not installable
                  Depends: libqt4-xml:i386 (>= 4:4.5.3) but it is not installable
                  Depends: libqtcore4:i386 (>= 4:4.7.0~beta1) but it is not installable
                  Depends: libqtgui4:i386 (>= 4:4.8.0) but it is not installable
                  Depends: libqtwebkit4:i386 (>= 2.2~2011week36) but it is not installable
                  Depends: libstdc++6:i386 (>= 4.2.1) but it is not installable
                  Depends: libx11-6:i386 but it is not installable
                  Depends: libxext6:i386 but it is not installable
                  Depends: libxss1:i386 but it is not installable
                  Depends: libxv1:i386 but it is not installable
                  Depends: libssl1.0.0:i386 but it is not installable
                  Depends: libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 but it is not installable
                  Recommends: sni-qt:i386 but it is not installable
                  Recommends: libasound2-plugins:i386 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

it recommends two files as seen above but it says that they are uninstallable which is why I am thinking that to try to install Skype on a raspberry pi that is running Ubuntu Mate 1.21. Is this not practical right now? I am just asking someone to confirm or to give me the solution to my issue (both how to fix the broken packages and also how to install Skype)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the Canonical repositories are enabled. it can be enabled through:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ $(lsb_release -sc) partner"
```

Add  32 bit support and install skype:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install skype
```